# How to optimize my queries to avoid full transaction log in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, transaction-log

I found my database over limit in Godaddy database server and i was told by their support team that this is because the full transaction log

After they truncate it as i don't have administrative rights on my shared hosting it got full once more in few weeks

They told me that is is due to my code and asks me to review my code to optimize it

But now i don't understand what is the meaning of review my queries

Is there any code to be written in my queries to avoid the full transaction log

> update upon members inquery
>
> .

my code is like this

```
        Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase dbHelper = new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABestoreConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand dbCommand = (SqlCommand)dbHelper.GetStoredProcCommand("Admin_FAQD");
        dbHelper.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@FAQID", SqlDbType.Int, fAQID);
        dbHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
        return true;
```

how to use begin transaction and commit with this code –

Another function i use to bulk insert data from excel file to SQL server table

```
     //series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our sql table
     OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(excelFileConnStr);
     OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(query, oledbconn);
     oledbconn.Open();
     OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
                        
     SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnStr, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints);

     bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
     while (dr.Read())
     {
         bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
     }
     oledbconn.Close();
```

how to use begin transaction and commit with this code as well –

Comment: You should change the database to simple recovery, if that meets the needs of your application.  That limits the size of the transaction log.

Comment: but godaddy support told me that this is not allowed on their shared hosting and told me as well that i must review my queries to optimize them

Comment: it can not be "full" but may utilize all available space

Comment: Yes and i want to know to make my queries don't use the transaction log.. godaddy told me review your queries.. and i don't know how to do that

Comment: Could you provide examples of the queries you run the most? Eg. repeated insert statements can quickly fill up the transaction log.

Comment: sorry i cant right the code in comments so i write an answer below .. could you please have a look on it .. i use this code on my site to execute transactions .. also i use a function written below as well to copy data from excel file to sql server tables .. i don't know to use begin transaction and commit with these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code does any BEGIN TRAN, make sure you're also issuing a COMMIT TRAN. Uncommitted transactions will keep the log growing even if you're not doing anything else that would otherwise cause it to grow.

Comment: my code is like this Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase dbHelper = new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABestoreConnectionString"].ToString());
 SqlCommand dbCommand =(SqlCommand) dbHelper.GetStoredProcCommand("Admin_FAQD");
dbHelper.AddInParameter(dbCommand,"@FAQID",SqlDbType.Int,fAQID);
dbHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
return true;}  catch (Exception){throw ;}

how to use begin transaction and commit with this code

Comment: sorry .. i write the code in an answer below because when i write it here as a comment it looks like a mess thanks please have a look on it